# How to get JSON data via Javascript with cookies authentication?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, authentication, cookies, rack

I'm building an application with Ruby on Rails. The application is a Javascript application that get data by JSON calls from the `api` application. It also provide the cross domain authentication for the application itself and the `api`.

I handle the cross domain authentication via making both application cookies with same secret session key and same name e.g. `_app_an_api_session`.

Now, I'll write down the senario and I'll show you when it fails.

The application domain is `domain.local` the api domain `api.domain.local`

Lets say that `api.domain.local/me` is a protected page. When I open it i got `unauthenticated`

When I go to the application and `sign in` and go to `api.domain.local/me` again, I can see the data in it. [Pass] [it works also for the opposite actions].

The problem is, for example, after `sign in` I want to load `api.domain.local/me` contents [JSON data] in `domain.local`, I can see in the console that the `status` is `(canceled)`.

In addition for debugging sake. I tried to see the `env` variable on each request to the `api`. So, when I access the `api.domain.local/me`directly, I can see the cookies hash in the console, else if it via the real application, there's no cookies/sessions at all.

So, how to make it possible to done this right?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the Same-Origin Policy that prevents communication between different domains and subdomains. You can resolve this either through using a proxy, JSON-P or an [external proxy](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/).

Comment: cookies across domain works fine since both apps shared some auth cookies. The problem is getting data of `/me` that requires auth via Javascript

Comment: It doesn't work. I can load `/user/2` that doesn't require authentication. But i can load `/me` that requires auth.

Comment: I think its an issue with sending credentials through xhr requests. I guess Twitter handle this with xd receiver. do you have any experience with this?